# Unable to install php5-pgsql on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-pgsql

I updated my OS from Ubuntu 14.04 to version 16.04, and php 7 was installed, but I want to use php 5.6. So I installed php 5.6 and tell Apache to use that version instead of php 7.

But I'm having problems installing php5-pgsql.

I tried with [this](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/p/php5-pgsql/install/index.html) tutorial, but I get the error

> "El paquete php5-pgsql no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete
>   hace referencia a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está
>   obsoleto o sólo se encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente"

what can I do?

Comment: This is an English language website, most of the readers cannot understand that error message.

Answer (score 16):

try this:

sudo apt-get install php5.6-pgsql

Hope it helps!

Comment: this works, but didnt work with bitnami lamp stack, but works on pure ubuntu when only apache and php are installed

Comment: This no longer works in 2023

Answer (score 3):

U can try the latest version.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```